# When 777ms are still not good enough (MariaDB tuning)

Tags: performance, mariadb, my.cnf

Over the past couple of months, I've been on a rampage optimising a Joomla website that I'm managing. When I first started, the homepage used to open in around 30-40 seconds, in spite of repeatedly upgrading my dedicated server, as suggested by the hosting firm.

I was able to bring the pagespeed down to around 800ms by religiously following all the recommendations of the likes of GT Matrix and PingdomTools, (such as using JCH-optimize, .htaccess caching and compression settings, and MaxCDN) but now I'm stuck optimising my my.cnf settings, trying various settings suggested on a number of related articles. The fastest I'm getting the homepage to open - with the current settings - is 777ms after refresh, which might not sound too bad, but look at the configuration of my dedicated server:

- 2 Quads, 128GB, 2x480GB SSD RAID
- CloudLinux/Cpanel/WHM
- Apache/suEXEC/PHP5/FastCGI
- MariaDB 10.0.17 (all tables converted to XtraDB/InnoDB)

The site traffic is moderate, 10,000 and 20,000 visitors per day, with around 200,000 pageviews.

These are the current my.cnf settings. My goal is to bring the pagespeed down to under 600ms, which should be possible with this kind of hardware, provided it is tuned the right way.

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
max_connections=10000
max_user_connections=1000
max_connect_errors=20
key_buffer_size=1G
join_buffer_size=1G
bulk_insert_buffer_size=1G
max_allowed_packet=1G
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file="diskar/mysql-slow.log"
long_query_time=40
connect_timeout=120
wait_timeout=20
interfactive_timeout=25
back_log=500
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size=512M
query_cache_limit=512K
query_cache_min_res_unit=2K
sort_buffer_size=1G
thread_cache_size=16
open_files_limit=10000
tmp_table_size=8G
thread_handling=pool-of-threads
thread_stack=512M
thread_pool_size=12
thread_pool_idle_timeout=500
thread_cache_size=1000
table_open_cache=52428
table_definition_cache=8192
default-storage-engine=InnoDB

[innodb]
memlock
innodb_buffer_pool_size=96G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=12
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=4G
innodb_log_bugger_size=1G
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:400M:autoextend
innodb_use_native_aio=1
innodb_doublewrite=0
innodb_user_atomic_writes=1
innodb_flus_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_compression_level=6
innodb_compression_algorithm=2
innodb_flus_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size=4G
innodb_log_files_in_group=3
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=16
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions=16
innodb_thread_concurrency
innodb_thread_concurrency=24
innodb_write_io_threads=24
innodb_read_io_threads=32
innodb_adaptive_flushing=1
innodb_flush_neighbors=0
innodb_io_capacity=20000
innodb_io_capacity_max=40000
innodb_lru_scan_depth=20000
innodb_purge_threads=1
innodb_randmon_read_ahead=1
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_write_io_threads=64
innodb_use_fallocate=1
innodb_use_atomic_writes=1
inndb_use_trim=1
innodb_mtflush_threads=16
innodb_use_mfflush=1
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_file_format=Barracuda
innodb_fast_shutdown=1
```

I tried Memcached and APCU, but it didn't work. The site actually runs 2-3 times faster with 'Files' as the caching handler in Joomla's Global Configuration. And yes, I ran my-sqltuner, but that was of no help.

I am newby as far as Linux is concerned and suspect that above settings could be improved. Any comments and/or suggestions?

Comment: Why do you assume it's a db issue?

Comment: Does the mysql slow log still report anything? Do any of the DB queries take a long time? How many queries does it tke to produce the front page (or others) Have you run Blackfire.io or Xhprof profilers against the PHP code? Does it have Opcache installed on PHP 5.6? Do you actually have appraching 100GB of data in the database?

Comment: opcache is installed. the rest I can't answer at this stage, so I'll investigate, or the answer is no. I doubt though that I can do much about the php code, because I'm using Joomla with standard extensions such as Jomsocial and EasyDiscuss which are both very demanding on the database. The main reason for posting this here is that I'm new to my.cnf tuning, so I suspect that I might have done something wrong.

Comment: Pingdom tools counts 80 requests for the homepage and takes 750ms to 1.3s to load.

Answer (score 0):

```
long_query_time=40
```

Set that to 1 so you can find out what the slow queries are.

```
max_connections=10000
```

That is unreasonably high.  If you come anywhere near it, you will have more problems than failure to connect.  Let's say only 3000.

```
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size=512M
```

The Query cache is hurting performance by being so large.  This is because *any* write causes *all* QC entries for the table to be purged.  Recommend no more than 50M.  If you have heavy writes, it might be better to change the type to `DEMAND` and pepper your `SELECTs` with `SQL_CACHE` (for relatively static tables) or `SQL_NO_CACHE` (for busy tables).

What OS?

Are the entries in `[innodb]` making it into the system?  I thought these needed to be in `[mysqld]`.  Check by doing `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';`.

Ah, buggers; a spelling error:

```
innodb_log_bugger_size=1G
innodb_flus_log_at_trx_commit=2
inndb_use_trim=1
```

and more??

After you get some data in the slowlog, run pt-query-digest, and let's discuss the top couple of queries.

Comment: I hand copied the my.cnf settings, hence the typos. I will try making the couple of suggested changes and remove the [innodb] header. I didn't know that the innodb settings have to be under the [mysqld] header. I thought these were just comment  items to make the file tidier.

Comment: Removing the [innodb] line made a huge difference. The MySQL service (MariaDB) no longer wanted to start up, complaining about all sorts of InnoDB settings. I ended up commenting them all out. My site actually got faster doing so, 756ms after refresh, probably because of the other changes I made as suggested by the Rick James: - max_connections=3000 - query_cache_type=1 - query_cache_size=50M I'm now adding the other Innodb related statements, one by one, to see whether they make any difference in speed.

Comment: Probably the most important for speed:  innodb_buffer_pool_size=96G, innodb_doublewrite=0, innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2.

Comment: You can't "tune you way out of performance problems", so the next thing to do is to look at the queries, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.